# Installing vrview locally

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to run vrview on my site but am receiving the

*"Unable to load texture" message.*

I have tried:

- Add Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" to .htaccess
- Added the header module to apache....and it still doesn't work.
- I even tried enabling CORS and still have the problem!!

I have read that an option is to download the vrview files to my local server.  I downloaded them and put them on my public folder!  NOW WHAT???  Which js should I add?

**view**

```
<script>
            window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad);

            function onVrViewLoad() {
                // Selector '#vrview' finds element with id 'vrview'.
                var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 400,
                    preview:'img/quienessomos/clinica360-preview.jpg',
                    image: 'img/quienessomos/clinica360.jpg',
                    is_stereo: true
                });
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: What kind of message is that? Can you share some of your code?

Comment: You can see the problem at http://dev.bienestardental.cl/quienessomos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the developer console: you are loading three.min.js using https and then some preview image using http. You should either load your whole website through https or three.min.js using http. Mixing these protocols causes errors in the browser

Comment: OK got it working on the server!!  Just doesnt work on my localhost!  thanks anyway.